# How to put "-" in an form html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on a form to fill out my bank account number, so I want to put a tick. Automatically so that it can be viewed more easily

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" name="account_number">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtPhoneNo").keyup(function (e) {
      if($(this).val().length === 14) return;
      if(e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 37 || e.keyCode === 39) return;
      let newStr = '';
      let groups = $(this).val().split('-');
      for(let i in groups) {
       if (groups[i].length % 4 === 0) {
        newStr += groups[i] + "-"
       } else {
        newStr += groups[i];
       }
      }
      $(this).val(newStr);
    });
})
```

```html
<input type='text' placeholder="please enter" id="txtPhoneNo" name='phone' maxlength='14'><BR>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```